# Python shutil move I/O error

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to find some files, create a folder and move the files in there.

```
def test():
    try:
        logfile = "C:\\Users\\alkis\\Desktop\\testouter\\test"
        result_dir = os.path.join(logfile, "testzip")
        print result_dir
        os.makedirs(result_dir)
        os.chmod(result_dir, stat.S_IWRITE)
        kpath = logfile + "\\*.jpg"
        print kpath
        files = glob.glob(kpath)
        for file in files:
           filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
           print filename
           os.chmod(filename, stat.S_IWRITE)
           shutil.move(filename, result_dir)
    except Exception, e:
        #shutil.rmtree(result_dir)
        print e.__doc__ + "\r\n"
        print e.message
    return
```

The error I am getting is: `MS-Windows OS call failed`
I check the permissions on my files and they are not read only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are listing each file, *removing* the extension, then trying to move that filename.

The extension is part of the filename, don't remove it. Windows Exlorer *hides* the extension only when displaying files.

You also don't need to call `os.chmod()` on the filename; just skip that step:

```
for file in files:
    filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    print filename
    shutil.move(filename, result_dir)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I printed the filenames but I just failed to notice that. If I call os.path.splitext(file)[0] I get it without the extension. Is it possible to have the same result plus the extension, without concat?